# detect error on asynchronous write to influxdb using python influxdb_client

Tags: asynchronous, error-handling, influxdb, influxdb-python

This is my code:

```
write_api = client.write_api(write_options=ASYNCHRONOUS)
write_api.write(bucket, org, data, write_precision=WritePrecision.US)
```

1 - How can I detect writing errors?

2 - Should I initialize `write_api` each time I want to write or I can initialize it once and use the same object all the time?

Answer (score 0):

```
callback = write_api.write(bucket, org, data, write_precision=WritePrecision.US)
callback.wait()
callback.get()
```

Is the only way I found. Unfortunately the wait basically makes it synchronous decreasing the performance.